# Firestore JS - incrementing within transactions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have some code that looks like the following:

```
export const createTable = async (data) => {
  const doc = db.collection("tables").doc();
  const ref = db
  .collection("tables")
  .where("userId", "==", data.userId)
  .orderBy("number", "desc").limit(1);

  db.runTransaction(async transaction => {
    const query = await transaction.get(ref);
    let number = 1;
    if (!query.empty) {
      const snapshot = query.docs[0];
      const data = snapshot.data();
      const id = snapshot.id;
      number = data.number + 1;
    }
    data = {number, ...data};
    transaction.set(doc, data);
  });
```

Basically I have a tables collection and each table has an auto generated number like #1, #2, #3

When creating new tables, I want to fetch the latest table number and create the new table with that number incremented by 1.

I wanted to wrap it in a transaction so that if a table created while running the transaction, it will restart so that I don't end up with duplicate numbers.

However, this errors out on the .get(), and from googling I've read that Firestore can't monitor a whole collection within transactions, but instead it requires a specific doc passed to it. Which I obviously can't do because I need to monitor for new docs created in that collection, not changes in a particular doc.

If so, what's the correct way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

The Firestore transaction API for client apps requires that you `get()` each individual document that you want to participate in the transaction.  So, if you have a query whose results you want to transact with, you will need to:

1. Perform the query (outside of the transaction)
2. Collect document references for each document in the result set
3. In the transaction, `get()` them all individually.

You will be limited to 500 documents per transaction.

If you want to dynamically look for new documents to modify, you will probably much better off implementing that on the backend using a [Firestore trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) in Cloud Functions to automatically handle each new document as they are created, without requiring any code on the client.

Comment: I can't do as described because my query fetches the document with the highest value of number. If I query it outside of the transaction, then get() inside the transaction, this will not cover a scenario when another document with a higher number gets inserted in the meantime by another user. Eg number is 2, my query gets me the ref, meanwhile number 3 is added, and my get() in the transaction would still return me the 2.

Comment: Please edit the question to explain in more detail what your requirements are.  What you have right now doesn't explain what you're trying to do, just that you have an error.  A transaction can't "listen" to query results - that doesn't scale.  If you want a transaction, you absolutely must accept that you need to call out the individual documents for that transaction.  If you want to listen to a query that might change over time, you can certainly use a listener for that, but then you will still have to perform a transaction separately.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're updating just one document, you **probably don't need** to use transactions for incrementing values.

You can use Firestore Increment to achieve this.

Here is an example taken from [here](https://fireship.io/snippets/firestore-increment-tips/):

```
const db = firebase.firestore();
const increment = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1);

// Document reference
const storyRef = db.collection('stories').doc('hello-world');

// Update read count
storyRef.update({ reads: increment });
```

This is the easiest way to increment values in Firestore.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can use this, I'm not incrementing an existing value but instead I need to fetch the max value from a collection and set the value in a new document based on that.